# Where can I find a similar font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I created this (partial) logo at least 3 years ago. I'm a programmer, not a designer, so when the site was complete all the image files were handed off to an actual designer. The designer has left the company, and no one can find the image files. They now want to create new materials using the same font, but I have no idea what font I used back then.

Can anyone either

- help me identify it,
- recommend a similar one?

They're particularly interested in matching the proportion of the font and the lower-case "l", which is somewhat serify, even though it's a sans font.

I've tried whatthefont.com, but it doesn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: I think there's bigger problems than at this company...such as not having proper file management and back up nor a properly designed visual identity. Maybe now is a good time to consider updating both? As for the font, browse myfonts for 'typewriter' and 'monospace' styles. The lowercase L is fairly distinctive, though I can't place it.

Comment: I agree, but I don't actually work for this company. I was a freelancer years ago, and once my contract was up that was supposed to be the end of it. Their file management and backup practices are not my concern; I was just trying to do them a favor by getting them the font I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The designer has left the company, and no one can find the image
>   files.

I thought every company have backup plans of each and every element...anyways do you have .psd file of the same?

And where ever I know this font have  `bevel and emboss effect` applied

I found some fonts which goes with Your "L" but they dont have other letter similar, so you can choose one of them if it's okay ....

- [skyhook-mono](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fontom-type/skyhook-mono/upright/)
- [Ocrk Light square](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/testpilot/ocrk/light-square/)
- [pennsylvania](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/pennsylvania/)

Comment: See comments above; I was a freelancer and no longer have anything to do with the company. Their backups are not my problem. No, I don't have the psd - when my contract was up, all originals were passed on to the in-house designer they hired. I'll take a look at the fonts you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/) gave me a fairly good match with [Vera Sans Mono](http://www.identifont.com/list?17+id+1+WC+1+IN5+1+6KN+2+4ZY+2+6ZL+3+27W2+3+1RX+3+64U+3+4BI+3+68N+4+69I+4+7LX+4+28Q+4+6BE+4+3GA+4+7BQ+4+CZM+4+7U7+4+3J0+4+2ZZ+4+315+4+7EA+4+3HH+4+9QR+4+4FS+4+37Z+4+380+4+P3N+4+7LO+5+6UQ+5):

[image: Sample]

Comment: Thanks! I had done the original development on Windows (blech!) and am now on Linux. I have vera sans, but couldn't remember what the windows version of it was. It's apparently DejaVu Sans Mono.